# Vuetify 3 v-navigation-drawer "right" not working?

Tags: vuetifyjs3, v-navigation-drawer

Is it possible that the Vuetify 3 v-navigation-drawer's "right" property is not (yet) working? The panel shows on the left side.

```
<v-navigation-drawer
    v-model="drawer"
    right
    temporary
    >
    <v-list class="mt-2">
        <v-list-item-group
            v-model="group"
            >
            <v-list-item
                to="changepassword"
            >
                <v-list-item-icon>
                      <v-icon icon="mdi-key-chain"/>
                </v-list-item-icon>
                <v-list-item-content>Change password</v-list-item-content>
            </v-list-item>
        </v-list-item-group>
    </v-list>
</v-navigation-drawer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, the correct setting is

```
location="right"
```